# Kubernetes: kubectl returns 404 not found when fetch pod logs

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to get logs from my pod, but it doesn't work for some reason though `kubectl describe pod` works well, `docker logs` works well. I have Kubernetes 1.2.3 Debian 8 x64 installed manually on a single node

```
  $ kubectl logs -f web-backend-alzc1 --namespace=my-namespace --v=6
  round_trippers.go:286] GET http://localhost:8080/api 200 OK in 0 milliseconds
  round_trippers.go:286] GET http://localhost:8080/apis 200 OK in 0 milliseconds
  round_trippers.go:286] GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/my-namespace/pods/web-backend-alzc1 200 OK in 1 milliseconds
  round_trippers.go:286] GET http://localhost:8080/api 200 OK in 0 milliseconds
  round_trippers.go:286] GET http://localhost:8080/apis 200 OK in 0 milliseconds
  round_trippers.go:286] GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/my-namespace/pods/web-backend-alzc1/log?follow=true 404 Not Found in 1 milliseconds
  helpers.go:172] server response object: [{
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log web-backend-alzc1)",
    "reason": "NotFound",
    "details": {
      "name": "web-backend-alzc1",
      "kind": "pods/log"
    },
    "code": 404
  }]
  helpers.go:107] Error from server: the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log web-backend-alzc1)
```

Is there something I should describe in RC scheme to enable logs for this pod?

I tried to recreate RC and look at journalctl, I see these messages:

```
  hyperkube[443]: I0510 12:14:13.754922     443 hairpin.go:51] Unable to find pair interface, setting up all interfaces: exec: "ethtool": executable file not found in $PATH
  hyperkube[443]: I0510 12:14:13.756866     443 provider.go:91] Refreshing cache for provider: *credentialprovider.defaultDockerConfigProvider
  hyperkube[435]: W0510 12:14:38.835863     435 request.go:344] Field selector: v1 - serviceaccounts - metadata.name - default: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
```

Comment: How did you start your node? Specifically, do you have the `--enable-debugging-handlers` flag set to false?

Comment: It's a regular EC2 node, I download binaries of hyperkube and kubectl, started kubelet, proxy, controller, scheduler and apiserver via systemd. This solution works fine for few months already on different machines, it's just I never tried to work to logs before

Comment: Sorry, I meant what command did you use to start the kubelet? (did you disable the `--enable-debugging-handlers` flag?)

Comment: Wow! I've restarted kubelet without this flag and it's working now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `--enable-debugging-handlers` flag being set to false, which prevents the kubelet from attaching to containers and fetching the logs. Restarting the kubelet without this flag (it defaults to `true`) should fix it.